# Migrating contract with truffle gives me transaction revert

Tags: migration, solidity, truffle

My contract `.sol` file looks like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol";

contract ERC777MainToken is ERC777{
  constructor(address[] memory defaultOperators) ERC777("COIN", "COIN", defaultOperators) { }
}
```

And the migration looks like this:

```
const ERC777MainToken = artifacts.require("ERC777MainToken");

module.exports = async function(_deployer) {
  const mainToken = await _deployer.deploy(ERC777MainToken, ["0x5d95F05Dd72A5cB9ea2ee2DC271B03A41C933Cad"])
};
```

On `truffle migrate` I get the following error:

```
"ERC777MainToken" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all require conditions.
   * Adding reason strings to your require statements.

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:74:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:61:1)
    at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:212:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.runAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:114:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:79:1)
    at runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:263:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:228:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:136:1)
```

Any Ideas why? I have check every constructor and no one has any require conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the problem. The ERC777 contract from open zeppelin  has an hardcoded memeber `_ERC1820_REGISTRY = IERC1820Registry(0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24)` which is the `global ERC1820 Registry` for the main net but since I am on local net this address is at most nothing.

```
contract ERC777 is Context, IERC777, IERC20 {
    using Address for address;

    IERC1820Registry constant internal _ERC1820_REGISTRY = IERC1820Registry(0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24);

    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

   ....
}
```

And the constructor is tring to access the contract on this address:

```
 constructor(
        string memory name_,
        string memory symbol_,
        address[] memory defaultOperators_
    ) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;

        _defaultOperatorsArray = defaultOperators_;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < defaultOperators_.length; i++) {
            _defaultOperators[defaultOperators_[i]] = true;
        }

        // register interfaces
        _ERC1820_REGISTRY.setInterfaceImplementer(address(this), keccak256("ERC777Token"), address(this));
        _ERC1820_REGISTRY.setInterfaceImplementer(address(this), keccak256("ERC20Token"), address(this));
    }
```

But since this address on the local net might be empty and 100% is not what it should be the transaction is reverted.

Comment: in that case how do you overcome this problem since development needs to continue on test/local net.

Answer (score 1):

If in your code you have a `require` or `revert` statement in your contract, add an error message like this: `require(condition, errorMessage);` or `revert (errorMessage);`